# I can't get some array from c# at WinForms with CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I have Win Forms Application with Chromium. My goal is getting string variable (json), witch had generated at C# land, for using with javascript function. I can't get it at javascript-land.

I created mefod getJSON() at JSObj.cs - it generated json. And I saw string from method. I registered oblect JSObj at Form1.cs (here I have Chromium). I called  JSObj.getJSON() from html with button, but I didn't json in javascript code!

```html
<button class="btn btn-info" id="btn3">Test Winform Interaction</button>
```

```
$("#btn3").on('click', function () {
            alert(jSObject.getJSON()[0]);
        });
```

```
public string getJSON()
        {
            DispHandler hand = new DispHandler(delegate
            {
                string directoryPath = @"C:\";
                List<SObject> sendObjects = new List<SObject>();
                DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
                FileInfo[] filesArray = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
                foreach (var el in filesArray)
                {
                    sendObjects.Add(new SObject(el.Name, directoryPath));
                }
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sendObjects);
                return json;
            });
            IAsyncResult resultObj = hand.BeginInvoke(null, null);
            var res = hand.EndInvoke(resultObj);
            return res;
        }
```

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();            
            _browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("jSObject", new JSObj());
        }
```

It was no errors. I expect getting json data in javascript-land.

Comment: You can use Devtools for debugging see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging In JavaScript the jSObject.getJSON() method will return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between C# and CEF is asynchronous, jSObject.getJSON() returns a Promise to result, not result itself. Try this JS code:

```
$("#btn3").on('click', function () {
    jSObject.getJSON().then(function (r) { alert(r[0]); });
});
```